# Reusable component not seen by children routes components

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I have 2 lazy loaded routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  }
];
```

And dashboard route has children routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'usuarios',
        component: UsersComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have created a toolbar reusable component, which I wanna render on dashboard router-outlet, but when I navigate to the children routes of dashboard module, angular compiler says that the app-toolbar is not a component.

I've added the component on Dashboard module and tried on AppModule too, but I get the same result.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem with the lazy loading routes in Angular, I believe. Although it is convenient to specify `LoadChildren` programmatically as you did, you have to use string instead, a la

```js
loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule',
```

Comment: on new angular versions, loadChildren: () => import(...).then(...) is the "correct" way for code splitting

Comment: I know. I created an app with angular version ^8, and it didn't work for me either because of lazy loading, so I had to use strings instead.